# Can I determine if a user is a contract manager?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is it possible, using the 3-legged authentication workflow, to determine if a user is an Autodesk contract (or software) manager using the OAuth API?

I've noticed the account:read and account:write scopes. Would this allow me to tell if a user is a contract manager?

Comment: Could you share more details on why you want to know if the user if contact manager? The current answer to the contact manager is no, contact management is not part of the Forge API as I know, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We are developing an application using Autodesk Forge in combination with the 3 legged authentication workflow. In the signup process I would like to restrict the signup process to users with a certain role in an organisation to make sure not everyone within a organisation can start a signup procedure. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: Sure, thank you for sharing the detail. I put my reply below, hope it helps in your case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the contract info is not part of the Forge platform, and there no API support querying such data for this purpose currently. However, BIM360 Account Admin API [GET users](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-GET/) supports telling the user role in these three types:

- account_admin: user has BIM 360 account administration access
- account_user : normal project user
- project_admin: user has Project administration privileges at a service level

And commonly, the contact manager will be the account admin of that BIM360 account. Therefore, you could use this as a workaround. Hope it helps, cheers!

**Note.** Account Admin API only accepts two-legged access token.